# Jquery: Select a href link and navigate with 'each' method

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, href, each

Is it possible using jQuery to select one full link that is in others 'tags'?

I would like select each href link of each item (`<li>`)..

My idea is to use the method `each` and then extract the link, for use to navigate then.

This is the part of the code of the page: http://pastebin.com/3Vjib4UR

Where in full code of page, there more `<li>` items in the `<ul>` tag.

*P.S: I would like use the script in an external plugin of firefox (Greasemonkey),and not direct in the page.*

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards.

Comment: Instead of coming up with clever workaround to display HTML tags, you could read the help page.

Comment: @SLaks, Just curious... help page for what?

Comment: @kchau: The help page for the SO editor.

Comment: @SLaks Now I'm curious, what was the clever workaround?

Comment: @box9: See the edit history.  < li>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or shorter:

```
var links = $('a').map(function(){ return this.href;}).get();
```

If you want to get only certain links, just adjust the selector, e.g.

```
$('ul li a')
```

You really should learn how [*selectors*](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) works in order to use jQuery efficiently.

Comment: with this,select me all href links in the page. I need only the href of each item (of each '< li>' tag). Thanks you again :)

Comment: Thanks you for all :-)   .But please for this time,you can write for me the code please? (I know that i have to use the 'child selector',but i don't know how :-( ). Thanks you anyway ;-)

Comment: @Luca: I already wrote it for you: `$('ul li a')` (note, this will select all `li` elements in *all* `ul` s. If you want to have a specific list, you have to restrict it further by e.g. giving the list an ID). Learn from the documentation. It provides a lot of examples an use cases.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
var arr = new Array();

$("a").each(function(){ arr.push($(this).attr("href"); });
```

Comment: with this,select me all href links in the page. I need only the href of each item (of each '< li>' tag). Thanks you again :)